# SQL: Удаление определённого количества записей через процедуру

Tags: sql

Всем привет. Мне необходимо написать процедуру, которая удаляет определённое количество строк, соответствующих заданному параметру (в нашем случае, устаревших).

Пока получается так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PR$DELETE_OLD_VIDEO_TRANSLATION_STATISTICS(obsolescence_time DATETIME, insert_limit int)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE batch_to_delete(id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
    INSERT INTO batch_to_delete SELECT id FROM videotranslationlog WHERE created < obsolescence_time LIMIT insert_limit;
  DELETE l FROM videotranslationlog l JOIN batch_to_delete b ON (b.id = l.id); //здесь проблема
  COMMIT;
END;
```

То есть, я беру первую, скажем, тысячу соответствующих параметрам записей и кладу их во временную таблицу. Потом я хочу удалить записи, id которых соответствуют id в таблице на удаление. Строка DELETE, мне кажется, удалит все записи вообще, потому что нет WHERE.

Подскажите, как поправить скрипт, чтобы он работал, как я описал?

Comment: Это Вам только кажется. Попробуйте на тестовой табличке...

Comment: то есть, должно отработать нормально? Мне тоже нравится, но Идея выделяет и ругается.

Comment: *но Идея выделяет и ругается* Ну синтаксис-то надо блюсти...

Comment: Хотя я лично не понимаю - почему нельзя сразу взять да удалить с LIMIT-ом?

Comment: По PRIMARY_KEY удаляется быстрее и меньше вероятностей, что остановит выполнение скрипта из-за какого-нибудь констрейта.

Comment: *По PRIMARY_KEY удаляется быстрее* Просто по PK - да. А вот с указанным довеском - гарантированно нет. *меньше вероятностей, что остановит выполнение скрипта из-за какого-нибудь констрейта* Констрейнт контролирует целостность данных при их изменении. Но ему глубоко фиолетово, какими процессами они изменяются. Предположение абсурдно.